# boost::range::combine does not work with std::subrange

Tags: c++, boost, c++20, std-ranges

I try to apply `boost::range::conbine` to a couple of `std::subrange`s but the example does not compile.

```
#include <array>
#include <ranges>
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  auto arr = std::array{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  auto firsts = std::ranges::subrange(arr.begin(), arr.end() - 1);  
  auto seconds = std::ranges::subrange(arr.begin() + 1, arr.end());  

  for (auto [f, s]: boost::range::combine(arr, arr)) {
    std::cout << f << " " << s << std::endl;
  }

  /*
  // Does not compile.
  for (auto [f, s]: boost::range::combine(firsts, seconds)) {
    std::cout << f << " " << s << std::endl;
  }
  */

  return 0;
}
```

What is the reason for boost not to support subrange? Or is it a bug?

Comment: *"Does not compile."* Providing error message might help. (trying with several compiler might also help, as error message might be clearer for one o them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subrange models a [`view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view), and in this particular case also [`sized_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/sized_range). Neither of these satisfy [`combine`'s required](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/combine.html) [Range Concept `SinglePassRange`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/concepts/single_pass_range.html).

The compiler tells you as much:

> `/home/sehe/custom/superboost/libs/range/include/boost/range/detail/combine_cxx11.hpp|25 col 59| error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(std::ranges::subrange<const int*, const int*, std::ranges::subrange_kind::sized>&)’`

### Using Boosts model instead

So you can use the Boost range model:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/3coTaqqja)**

```
#include <array>
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
// #include <ranges>

int main() {
    static constexpr std::array arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    fmt::print("combine arrays: {}\n", boost::range::combine(arr, arr));

#if 1
    auto firsts  = boost::make_iterator_range(arr.begin(), arr.end() - 1);
    auto seconds = boost::make_iterator_range(arr.begin() + 1, arr.end());
#else
    auto firsts  = std::ranges::subrange(arr.begin(), arr.end() - 1);
    auto seconds = std::ranges::subrange(arr.begin() + 1, arr.end());
#endif

    fmt::print("combine ranges: {}\n", boost::range::combine(firsts, seconds));
}
```

Printing

```
combine arrays: [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
combine ranges: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

### Use `std::views::zip` instead

If you have a compiler that implements c++23 library supports already, you can use [`std::views::zip`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_view)

### Use RangeV3 library instead

This implementation contains things not (yet) standardized, and also supports `zip`

### Extend Boost Range

You can make Boost recognize `std::ranges::subrange`. I think [Method 2: Provide Free-standing Functions And Traits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/extending/method_2.html) is probably appropriate. The **absolute** bare minimum allows it to work:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/z1YrPYPrY)**

```
#include <array>
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <ranges>

namespace boost {
    template <typename I, auto K> struct range_iterator<std::ranges::subrange<I, I, K>> {
        using type = I;
    };

    template <typename I, auto K> auto range_begin(std::ranges::subrange<I, I, K> const& r) {
        return r.begin();
    }
} // namespace boost

int main() {
    static constexpr std::array arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    fmt::print("combine arrays: {}\n", boost::range::combine(arr, arr));

    auto firsts  = std::ranges::subrange(arr.begin(), arr.end() - 1);
    auto seconds = std::ranges::subrange(arr.begin() + 1, arr.end());

    fmt::print("combine ranges: {}\n", boost::range::combine(firsts, seconds));
}
```

Printing

```
combine arrays: [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5)]
combine ranges: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

### Summary/Notes

The above subtly assumes sized subranges (K is `subrange_kind​::​sized`), by requiring the sentinel is just an iterator. This is not very accurate (see e.g. [`sized_sentinel_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/sized_sentinel_for)) but it was the simplest thing to do for the purpose of teaching Boost how to use the subranges from your question.

Comment: The root cause of the issue is simply that `subrange` does not have a member type alias named `iterator`. Does this have anything to do with your explanation throughout?

Comment: @康桓瑋 That's not entirely accurate. Boost Range does not require the nested typedef, that's why linked [the concept requirements](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/concepts/single_pass_range.html). The nested typedef is merely [used by the primary template](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/concept_implementation/semantics/metafunctions.html). So yes, your analysis matches mine, except that I linked to concept docs for a more accurate description of the requirements.

Comment: Ok, then what *exactly* is lacking in `subrange` that makes it unsatisfactory to Single Pass Range? I still can't figure it out from your explanation. And what does this have to do with subrange being a `view` and `sized_range`? I don’t know the reason why you mentioned this, these two are completely different concepts from Single Pass Range.

Comment: That's exactly the point! They implement different concepts. Some people (apparently including the OP) expect all ranges are "just ranges" (and thus interoperable). To see what **exactly** is lacking "about" (not "in") subrange, just look at the working example - where I extend Boost Range to adapt `std::subrange` to satisfy SingePassRange. Note also the link to the documentation that explains this ([Method 2](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/extending/method_2.html))

Comment: So I can conclude that `subrange` is *not* suitable for boost range systems. In order for boost to recognize it, we need to specialize `range_iterator`? Note that we do not need to specialize `range_begin`, just specializing `range_iterator` is [enough](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/nMe73dTGM).

Comment: Indeed. Yes, the [primary template for `range_begin`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/concept_implementation/semantics/functions.html) would [work](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/zsMP391sx) because of [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).